# How to get hwid like in image

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio, hwid

I want get this type of hwid in a textbox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSahM.jpg

Can anybody help me with this. I also tried
HWID = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;

But getting hwid like S-1-5-21-3242323702-742451283-1005058250-1001
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the hardware id in the image? Any description?

Comment: I also want to know sir. Acutally this is hwid program from Wilcom EmbroideryStudio. And installation of wilcom is to hard and i am making One Click installer using C#.

Comment: `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User` is clearly not identifying the hardware, but the user.